# Quadruple precision for abs and sign

Tags: fortran, precision, fortran90, gfortran

I am trying to change the precision of the `abs` and `sign` with gfortran (gcc version 5.3.1 and x86_64-linux-gnu). 
I know I can change to `dabs` and `dsign` to have double precision but what about quad precision, is it possible?

For `sqrt(x)` for instance, I simply change to x**(0.5q0) with the arg defined as a `real(16)`. I read that some compilers do not have the intrinsic routines implemented in quad or extended precision, see e.g. [here](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Fortran/comp.lang.fortran/2009-02/msg00668.html).

Comment: if your compiler supports quad precision you can (should) simply use the generic intrinsic, ie, `sqrt(x)` where x is declared quad precision.  You should never replace `sqrt` with `**.5` at any precision

Comment: Why not overload them using an interface?

Comment: Don't use `dabs` and `dsin`. The new shiny FORTRAN 77 brought us generic intrinsics, use them!

Answer (score 4):

If `gfortran` has been compiled with support for libquadmath (on Linux it typically is), then it supports this right away. All you need to do is declare your variables and literals quadruple precision, and use the generic versions `abs` and `sign`.

However, using `real(16)` is not portable (and outdated). Better use something standardized such as `selected_real_kind(p=30)`.

Here is a short example to illustrate this:

```
program test
  integer, parameter  :: qp = selected_real_kind(p=30)
  real(qp)            :: a

  a = -2._qp

  print *, abs(a)
  print *, sqrt(-a)
end program
```

The output is:

```
2.00000000000000000000000000000000000      
1.41421356237309504880168872420969818
```

Compare this to the result of Wolfram alpha:

```
1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176
```

Answer (score 0):

Or...
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/525335

```
PROGRAM!SUBROUTINE!FUNCTION
USE ISO_C_BINDING
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL(KIND=C_LONG_DOUBLE) :: A
!or maybe...
REAL(C_LONG_DOUBLE)      :: B
...
```

Comment: The table in your link says that `C_LONG_DOUBLE` is `"REAL(KIND=8 or 16)"` so it is NOT guaranteed to be quadruple precision. Not even with that compiler which is different from OP's gfortran.

Comment: Indeed *"On the x86 architecture, most C compilers implement long double as the 80-bit extended precision type supported by x86 hardware (sometimes stored as 12 or 16 bytes to maintain data structure alignment), as specified in the C99 / C11 standards (IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic (Annex F)).* **An exception is Microsoft Visual C++ for x86, which makes long double a synonym for double."**  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double It is an exception, but rather an important one.